# How does javascript eval handle 'this'

Tags: javascript, eval, call, apply

I ran tests in Firefox 3.6.11, if that matters, and eval misbehaves in the context of call and apply. It somehow jumps over the current 'this' object. Why?

```
dojo.provide("yal-js.tests.javascript");

function evaltest () {
    var dis=this;
    // it works now... returns 2 on call and apply
    return eval("(function() {return this.testValue;}).call(dis);");
    // this, however, didn't work: it returned 1, not 2
    //return eval("(function() {return this.testValue;})();");
}
function controltest() {
    return this.testValue;
}

var testValue=1;
var testObj={testValue: 2};

doh.register("tests.javascript",
    new TFRunGroup(

        ["direct",
            function () {doh.assertEqual(1,controltest());} ],
        ["call",
            function() {doh.assertEqual(2, controltest.call(testObj) );}],
        ["apply",
            function() {doh.assertEqual(2, controltest.apply(testObj) );}],
        ["eval direct",
            function () {doh.assertEqual(1,evaltest());} ],
        ["eval call",
            function() {doh.assertEqual(2, evaltest.call(testObj) );}],
        ["eval apply",
            function() {doh.assertEqual(2, evaltest.apply(testObj) );}]
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

this at javascript is an object that called function,
when you use `object.function()` then `this` is `object`,
when you use `function.call(object,...)` then `this` is `object`,
when you use `function.apply(object,...)` then `this` is object,
when you use `new constructor(...)` then `this` is `new constructed object`,
otherwise `this` is `the global object` in brower it is `window`.

Comment: @Dmitri: Maybe he believes that `eval` is not the problem with your code. And please be a litte more courteous with people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`call` takes in, as its first argument, the value of `this` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)). So in the first line that works

```
return eval("(function() {return this.testValue;}).call(dis);");
```

you are passing it `dis` which points to `evaltest`, so `this.testValue` points to `evaltest.testValue`.

In the second line that doesn't work

```
return eval("(function() {return this.testValue;})();");
```

you are passing it `null` for `this`, so `this.testValue` is set to the window's `this.testValue` object.